# python-requests and complicated forms

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to make a web scraper for my university web, but I can't get past the login page.

```
import requests
URL = "https://login.ull.es/cas-1/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fcampusvirtual.ull.es%2Flogin%2Findex.php%3FauthCAS%3DCAS"
USER = "myuser"
PASS = "mypassword"

payload = {
    "username": USER,
    "password": PASS,
    "warn": "false",
    "lt": "LT-2455188-fQ7b5JcHghCg1cLYvIMzpjpSEd0rlu",
    "execution": "e1s1",
    "_eventId": "submit",
    "submit": "submit"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(URL, data=payload)
    #r = s.get(r"http://campusvirtual.ull.es/my/index.php")

    with open("test.html","w") as f:
        f.write(r.text)
```

That code is obviously not working and I don't know where's the mistake, I tried putting only the username and the password in the payload (the other values are in the source code of the web that are marked as hidden) but that is also failing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Is there any error thrown by python? What is the content in `r.text`?

Comment: Please state what you expect and what actually happens. If you say "obiously not working" it is hard to find out what went wrong. Also you should tell us what error messages you receive.

Comment: I suggest you use https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Pycas to make life easier.

Comment: Are you sure about your url? I think that the right one is https://login.ull.es/cas-1/login

Comment: @Llopis the extra suffix is just the page to redirect to after the log in.

Answer (score 6):

The `"lt": "LT-2455188-fQ7b5JcHghCg1cLYvIMzpjpSEd0rlu"` is a session ID or some sort of anti-CSRF protection or similar (wild guess: hmac-ed random id number). What matters is that **it is not a constant value**, you will have to read it from the same URL by issuing a GET request.

In the `GET` response you have something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Additionally, there is a `JSESSIONID` cookie that might be important.

This should be your flow:

1. GET the `URL`
2. extract the `lt` parameter and the `JSESSIONID` cookie from the response
3. fill the `payload['lt']` field
4. set cookie header
5. POST the same `URL`.

Extracting the cookie is very simple, see the `requests` documentation.

Extracting the `lt` param is a bit more difficult, but you can do it using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) package. Assuming that you have the response in a variable named `text`, you can use:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup

payload['lt'] = soup(text).find('input', {'name': 'lt', 'type': 'hidden'}).get('value')
```